# converting story board from iphone to ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a storyboard for my iphone version of my app and I want to have the same storyboard for my ipad version (only bigger). My story board only has text and buttons is there anyway I can just convert the whole thing and increase the size by 2, or do have to resize everything manually?

Answer (score 3):

You really need to do more than just resize you know.  iPad users don't generally enjoy running iPhone apps at double size on the iPad and it sounds like that's what you're proposing to do.

In your storyboard you can drag and drop from your iPhone screens to iPad to get all of the elements into the iPad storyboard.  Then maybe you will tweak a bit to make it more iPad friendly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you will need to create a new storyboard and set that as the storyboard for iPad (app settings).  You will then need to create the content manually (you can copy and paste the objects and use the existing controller classes though (will need to wire up the objects).